# Htaccess rewrite with optional parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have little understanding of HTACCESS, even though I have spent a long time looking into it. I think the real reason is because regular expressions go above and beyond my capacity.

Currently, in HTACCESS, I have use this line:

```
RewriteRule ^website/([^/]+)(/([^/]+))?$ controller/url.php?method=$1&param=$3
```

This will allow users to have a nice url that looks like www.website.com/website/method/optional_parameter

How could I add a second and third optional parameter to the HTACCESS rewrite line?

Comment: Provide some examples of your pretty URLs and their actual rewritten URLs on your server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to allow the second group to contain the rest of the URL after your "method" group.

```
RewriteRule ^website\/([^/]+)\/(.*)$ controller/url.php?method=$1&params=$2
```

Then use PHP to split params at each `/`

Hope that helps.

Comment: www.website.com/website/method/optional_parameter returns a 404 error. www.website.com/website/method/optional_parameter/param works, but param needs to be optional.

Comment: Ah, then you can use a rule more similar to your original: `RewriteRule ^website\/([^/]+)(/([^/]+))?$ controller/url.php?method=$1&params=$3`